# retain certain file using .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I think I'm using .gitignore wrongly. I try to retain my `config/db.js` to have 2 version, one is to connect to localhost db on my developement environment, one is to connect to live db.

I created .gitignore file and put in `config/db`, so that I can achieve that. I commit and push everything is working ; but when I put, someone `config/db.js` got overwritten. What's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove config/db.js from git and then ignore it

```
$ git rm --cached config/db.js
$ echo "config/db.js" >> .gitignore
```

Comment: do I need to push?

Comment: next time I pull when it overwrite my config/db.js?